# Overloading the Assignment operator for character Array in c++

Tags: c++

It can be the worse questions I am going to ask but I want to overload the Assignment Operator for character Array so basically, I can use it as a string.
This is what I wanted to do.

```
char c1[]="This";
char c2[10];
c2 = c1;
```

This is what I have tried so far and yes it didn't work out.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void operator = (char *c1, char *c)
{
    for(int idx = 0; c[idx] != 0; idx++)
    {
        c1[idx] = c[idx];
    }
    c1[idx] = 0;
}
int main(void)
{  
    char c[] = "This";
    char c1[10];
    c1 = c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `std::string`.

Comment: I can use that but this will cause unpredictable results in a file handling.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  When a C++ programmer sees pointer assignment, they expect pointers to be assigned.  This is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: More overt, when *any* programmer sees one native pointer assigned to another, they expect an address value-copy. That operator as you have it is literally `strcpy` so.. dare I ask what's wrong with your `strcpy` ?

Comment: Well I am doing a project and I have multiple classes with char Array data members I have to read the data from the files and then assign it to other classes although I could have used the std::string this will not work while reading data from the file also it would be easy if I could assign the char arrays like this.
Also, I want to know if this is not working then why and is there any way to do it.

Comment: You're still describing your "solution", which is no solution.  What exactly is the problem?  As to `std::string` "not working" -- `std::string line;  while (std::getline(file, line)) { do stuff with line; };`

Comment: You can't put data in the class by getline()

Comment: Given your comment in the answer provided, this all boils down to "how to read binary data into an object"?  If so, then this is the `X` of the `XY` that should have been stated from the very beginning.

Comment: Nope, I know how to read and write binary object from the binary files.
I am using char array Data members for reading and writing the data in the class from the binary files.
Let' say i copied that Data in one object then now I have to copy it to another object i could have used the strcpy() but i tried overloading the assignment operator it's that simple i just wanted to know why it's not working and is there any way to do it

Comment: @eerorika has already answered your question it's not possible to you can't overload operators for the predefined data types.

Comment: *i just wanted to know why it's not working* -- It doesn't work because C++ does not work this way.  I know you're trying to stick with your "solution" as much as possible, but it is no solution.  Second, if you have two structs, simply using `=` does a copy of structs since structs are copyable.  `struct foo { members };  int main() { foo f1;  foo f2;... f1 = f2;}` copies `f2` to `f1`, including arrays that are members.

Comment: Well, You can get understand this with this simple line.
This is not possible. The C++ language does not allow defining operator overloads to anything other than classes.
@eerorika has already Answered this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to overload the Assignment Operator for character Array

This is not possible. The C++ language does not allow defining operator overloads to anything other than classes.

Some alternatives:

- Wrap the array as a member of a class and define assignment operator for that class. This is what `std::array` is, although it uses the implicit assignment operator which behaves differently from your operator (you cannot assign arrays of different size).
- Just use a function instead of an operator. Your operator is pretty much identical to `std::strcpy`.

Note that the shown implementation is potentially unsafe (just like `std::strcpy` is)  since it can easily accidentally overflow the target array.

---

> > use std::string
>
> this will cause unpredictable results in a file handling.

`std::string` will not cause unpredicatble results in a file handling.

Comment: While reading the string members of our class our code literally fills them byte by byte. While it makes sense for floats and ints it won't work for strings.

Comment: Here you go, my friend:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712343/use-c-strings-in-file-handling

Comment: @ArslanIftikhar Did you read the answers? There are solutions to that problem other than "don't use `std::string`". Just because you cannot serialise a `std::string` with trivial copy, doesn't mean that `std::string` cannot be serialised.

Comment: The easiest way to solve this is to not use C++ strings in that class. Work out the maximum length for each of the strings you will be storing, and make a char array that is one byte longer (to allow for the 0-terminator). Now you can read and write that class as binary without worrying about serialization etc.

Comment: @ArslanIftikhar That works if you know the size of each of the stored strings at compile time. Also, without proper serialisation the file won't be portable to other systems. If those aren't a problem for your program, then you don't need to use `std::string`. It's still an option though.

Comment: Yeah, portability is not a problem for me.
Anyways I got you answers and thanks

Comment: you can also have operator usage in structs

Comment: @serup structs are classes.

Comment: @eerorika well technically they are not, but I understand what you mean

Comment: @serup Technically, they are. Unions are classes too.